# #1054 - Unknown column 'b.ID_TRANSAKSIJUAL' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Here is my query in MySQL. I don't know why the field is unknown

```
SELECT `a`.`NAMA_BULAN` AS `Bulan`,
    CASE WHEN `b`.`ID_TRANSAKSIJUAL` IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE `b`.`ID_TRANSAKSIJUAL`
    END AS `Total_Pendapatan`
    FROM `tbl_bulan` AS `a`
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MONTH(`tbl_transaksi_jual`.`TGL_TRANSAKSI`) AS `TGL_TRANSAKSI` , COUNT(`tbl_transaksi_jual`.`ID_TRANSAKSIJUAL`) AS `TOTAL_STLH_DISC`
        FROM `tbl_transaksi_jual`
        WHERE `tbl_transaksi_jual`.`ID_CABANG`=1 AND 
            YEAR(`tbl_transaksi_jual`.`TGL_TRANSAKSI`)= 2016
        GROUP BY MONTH(`tbl_transaksi_jual`.`TGL_TRANSAKSI`) 
        ) AS `b` ON `a`.ID_BULAN = `b`.`TGL_TRANSAKSI`
    ORDER BY `a`.ID_BULAN ASC
```

Comment: There are two columns in `b`: TGL_TRANSAKSI and TOTAL_STLH_DISC

Answer (score 1):

Subquery `b` doesn't return a column named `ID_TRANSAKSIJUAL`. It returns the count of this column in `TOTAL_STLH_DISC`, so you should test that in the main query.

You can also use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` instead of the `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT `a`.`NAMA_BULAN` AS `Bulan`,
       IFNULL(b.TOTAL_STLH_DISC, 0) AS Total_Pendapatan
FROM `tbl_bulan` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(`tbl_transaksi_jual`.`TGL_TRANSAKSI`) AS `TGL_TRANSAKSI`,
           COUNT(`tbl_transaksi_jual`.`ID_TRANSAKSIJUAL`) AS `TOTAL_STLH_DISC`
    FROM `tbl_transaksi_jual`
    WHERE `tbl_transaksi_jual`.`ID_CABANG`=1 AND 
        YEAR(`tbl_transaksi_jual`.`TGL_TRANSAKSI`)= 2016
    GROUP BY MONTH(`tbl_transaksi_jual`.`TGL_TRANSAKSI`) 
    ) AS `b` ON `a`.ID_BULAN = `b`.`TGL_TRANSAKSI`
ORDER BY `a`.ID_BULAN ASC
```